# Does Dumbledore know from the start that Voldemort is the one attacking the students in the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

> “What does this mean, Albus?” Professor McGonagall asked urgently.
>
> “It means,” said Dumbledore, “that the Chamber of Secrets is indeed open again.” Madam Pomfrey clapped a hand to her mouth. Professor McGonagall stared at Dumbledore.
>
> “But, Albus . . . surely . . . who?”
>
> **“The question is not who,” said Dumbledore, his eyes on Colin. “The question is, how. . . .”**

He already knows that it is Voldemort, that's why he's not suspecting Harry. And I don't know if there's any *Legilimency* involved (because it's not stated in the book, i guess).
I'm not sure with this but what's your thoughts?

Comment: Definitely looks like he thought for certain that Voldemort was behind it. He is confused as to how a dead guy is able to open it.

Thanks for pointing this out! HP is a gift that just keeps on giving :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes.

Dumbledore suspected that Voldemort was behind the attacks the first time the Chamber was opened, even if he wasn't able to prove anything.

> "Only the Transfiguration teacher, Dumbledore, seemed to think that Hagrid was innocent. He persuaded Dippet to keep Hagrid and train him as gamekeeper. Yes, I think Dumbledore might have guessed. Dumbledore never seemed to like me as much as the other teachers did..."
>   "I bet Dumbledore saw right through you," said Harry, his teeth gritted.
>   <sub>*(Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 17, The Heir of Slytherin)*.</sub>

He doesn't need to use Legilimency (and I'm not sure who he'd perform it on, anyway). When the attacks started again Dumbledore knew that Voldemort must have had something to do with it. As soon as he saw the writing on the wall proclaiming the opening of the Chamber he would've known that Voldemort was somehow involved. But he didn't understand *how* Voldemort could be influencing Hogwarts in his current spirit-like condition. That's why he says the question is not who but how.

He certainly made the link to Voldemort being in the Chamber without Harry telling him.

> "What interests *me* most," said Dumbledore gently, "is how Lord Voldemort managed to enchant Ginny, when my sources tell me he is currently in hiding in the forests of Albania."
>   <sub>*(Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 18, Dobby's Reward)*.</sub>

Dumbledore comes out with this unprompted, showing that he knew that Voldemort was involved all along. What he lacked was the knowledge of the diary to understand *how* Voldemort was able to do it.

Comment: Well, we can certainly trust the Dark Lord himself on this! :)

Comment: @Bellatrix You mean to say there are times you shouldn't trust him? Maybe for many people but surely not you, Miss Bella, dedicated and loyal Death Eater that you are? Of course you trust him (you just had no idea since you were in a certain prison) *always* so you can trust him here too, yes?

Comment: @Pryftan I meant that we should trust the Dark Lord himself above anyone *else* who answers. ;)

Comment: @Bellatrix Yes, but for you it's **in general** or perhaps **'Always**' (Yes that was **really really* bad esp since that quote is my favourite from HP and it is one that resonates strongly with me as does Severus's entire character...). So the point is you added '**on this!**' and I as a literal thinker interpret it as you saying there are things you should not trust him on it! Of course you did think he was mistaken with Severus and if only a certain Molly hadn't clobbered you (instead of say mollycoddled?) you'd have found this out before the end... Alas for you died before this revelation.

Comment: @Pryftan Of course I trust the Dark Lord! He was mistaken with Snape, indeed, but he is still far superior to most wizards! Molly perhaps hasn’t done as much damage to me as most think. I’m alive, well, and still the best user of Unforgivable Curses around! ;)

Comment: @Bellatrix Hahaha. Except the Killing Curse, right? Though you certainly use it indiscriminately you tend to favour a certain painful curse instead whereas your master prefers the former. Of course Harry would disagree and say: 'Albums Dumbledore is the greatest sorcerer in the world!' (or something like that). Wonder what he says now after Severus killed him.... We know what you'd say though. We know what Voldemort would say too even though he was fearful of Dumbledore. Ah well, just wanted to confirm that you meant you always trust your master (except about Severus).

Comment: @Pryftan I’m quite skilled at the Killing Curse, I simply prefer the Cruciatus Curse because it keeps the fun going on for longer! Why kill them quickly when I can make them suffer first?! The Dark Lord prefers being efficient. I think a quick death is too good for our enemies, and I enjoy their pain!

Comment: @Bellatrix Naturally, naturally. He does enjoy it too, after all. Of course causing dementia means they won't really remember what happened to them so you probably went too far there anyway. And I dare say that soon someone will accuse this thread of going too far too so probably should stop now...